# Как правильно сделать перевод графического меню?

Tags: python, tkinter

Создал меню с пунктом выбора языка приложения (tkinter). А как правильно теперь сделать перевод всех button, label, entry?

Comment: Пакет msgcat предоставляет набор функций, которые можно использовать для управления многоязычными пользовательскими интерфейсами. https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/msgcat.html и модуль стандартной библиотеки gettext - Услуги многоязычной интернационализации https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html, из ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044407/tkinter-app-allowing-for-multiple-languages

Comment: Можно посмотреть для общего понимания проблемы https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mWCzg31NCM

Comment: спасибо, устроил вариант в ответе на вопрос другого пользователя.